# I would like to play 2 audio links after one another with <embed> in HTML

Tags: html, audio, embed, external, playlist

I have two external audio files to play in a role and I would like it to auto play when my website is loaded. I am making a dictionary like application, so I need it to speak the word and the translation. I wonder what I should do. I tried the  but it only plays the first audio. I don't know how to set another audio to play after the first one is finished. I think that I might need to create a playlist. I have tried with .asx, but  it doesn't work. The link to my audios are:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sv&q=hur+m%C3%A5r+du

and

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=how+are+you

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way I found. I used m3u file to create a playlist and then call it in  by set src="playlistname.m3u"